# Does a user need to authorize my facebook app to post through a feed dialog on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I want to use the Facebook [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) on a website.  It appears that I need to create an app in order to use it.  Is this correct?

Will visitors to the website be required to authorize my Facebook app before posting through the feed dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is correct you need to create a Facebook app to get your app id and app secret.
The user will not need to authorize your app for the feed dialog.

As Micah said, the documentation on the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) stipulates :

> This does not require any extended permissions.

Comment: But after the first (JavaScript) example on the feed dialog documentation page, it says `Note that the above example assumes that the user is already logged in and has authorized your application.`

Comment: The best way to know is to try it ;)
I just tried the example on my server with my own app id and i made sure the app was not authorized on my account and i logged out.

If not logged in : there is a pop-up for logging in.
If logged in, there is no permission needed, you see the dialog as seen in the Feed Dialog documentation[link](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/Feed%20Dialog.png)
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

From that link:

> This does not require any extended permissions.

So no, users would not be required to authorize the app.

Comment: It also says on that page `Note that the above example assumes that the user is already logged in and has authorized your application.`  That makes me think that they need to authorize it, but not grant it any additional permissions.

Comment: Yah, that's some goofy dialog.  Have you used feed dialog on any website before?  If not, see if you can find one and see whether you have to 'authorize' it.  That's probably the easiest way to check.